# Scroll Infinito Con Jquery y Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hola he estado ensamblando este código que funciona en su parte de la condición de la altura del scroll pero no en la parta en la cual el AJAX tiene que meter de forma automática el .html qué falla?

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var distanceFromBottom = Math.floor($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() - $(window).height());

    if(distanceFromBottom < 10000) {
           $.ajax({
  url: "estrutura.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="scrollbox">
        <div id="page_1" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_2" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_3" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_4" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_5" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_6" class="pagina">ee</div>
        <div id="page_7" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_8" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_9" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_10" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_11" class="pagina">ee</div>
        <div id="page_12" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_13" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_14" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_15" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_16" class="pagina">ee</div>
        <div id="page_17" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_18" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_19" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_20" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_21" class="pagina">ee</div>
        <div id="page_22" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_23" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_24" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_25" class="pagina">rr</div>
        <div id="page_26" class="pagina">ee</div>        
    </div>
```

Comment: Si el id del `<div>` es `scrollbox`, deberías usar `$('#scrollbox').append(...)`... como primer paso.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que el error sea que invocas la url equivocada? `url: "estrutura.html"` parece que falta una "C" debería ser **estruCtura**.

Comment: jajaja @Equiso no, suelo escribir los nombres mal intencionadamente cuando no son archivos definitivos.

Comment: A cualquiera le puede pasar, solo me aseguraba :).  Cuando dices que no funciona ¿es porque sale algún error o simplemente no agrega nada?

Comment: @Equiso no agrega nada en absoluto...

Comment: En tu script veo que lo agregas al elemento `$("#results")` pero en el html veo que el id del elemento es `scrollbox`, verificaste eso también como comentó rnd

Comment: y si no es eso, ¿has visto si el request de ajax está trayendo el resultado que esperas en el panel de network?

Comment: He comprobado ambas cosas y no funciona en ninguno de los dos casos, es una cosa extraña?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir más código? (en concreto la parte donde se encuentre el elemento con id `results`). También, ¿hay algún error en la consola?

Comment: He probado su código y me funciona perfectamente si no he entendido mal su duda. Tuve que añadir un par de lineas mas de datos para que inicialmente ya exista el scroll pero funciona. Prueba a ver si eso es lo que necesitabas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a añadir un alert aqui para comprobar que la funcion realmente devuelve el html:

```
if(distanceFromBottom < 10000) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "estrutura.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
           alert(html)
           $("#results").append(html);
        }
    });
}
```